# LINQ Expression tree avoid inner cast to object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Having this kind of expression `Expression<Func<SampleType, object> sortField = entity => entity.UpdateDate` where `UpdateDate` is a `DateTime`, when I debug into the expression body at runtime, the expression is translated like this `Convert(entity.UpdateDate)` casting it into a `System.Object`, that's the usual mechanic.

My issue has to do with an ORM driver that supports LINQ sort fields but it is unable to understand the `Convert`.

So, Is there a way to avoid this inner cast?

(the driver must be passed with `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the required type is `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`, then you cannot create the tree without the cast. Either your ORM has to handle the cast (something along the lines as @Matias Cicero suggested), or you need to pass in an `Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>`, which is how most of the ORMs handle it as far as I know.

Comment: I mark it as correct, since it's the direct answer to the question. I posted the issue in the ORM driver's JIRA.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having this same issue on a project a time ago.

If you have access to your ORM source code, and you're able to modify it, 
I think here's is how I parsed the expression:

```
Expression body = sortExpression;

if (body is UnaryExpression) body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
if (!(body is MemberExpression)) throw new ArgumentException("Sort expression is invalid");

PropertyInfo property = ((MemberExpression)body).Member as PropertyInfo;
if (property == null) throw new ArgumentException("Sort expression must always be a property access");
```

Let's look at what I'm doing.

1. I check if the expression is an ***unary expression*** (`Convert(entity.UpdateDate)` is an unary expression), if it is, I proceed to identify the expression's operand, which will be `entity.UpdateDate` in your example.
2. I check if this new expression is a ***member expression***, i.e. is trying to access a member (a field, a property, or even a method) (`entity.UpdateDate` is a member expression)
3. If it is not a ***member expression*** then I consider the whole expression invalid
4. If it is, then I get the member being accessed, which will be the `UpdateDate` property in your case.
5. Now I have my property as a `PropertyInfo` which is relatively easy to handle.

Comment: I see your point, but I'd prefer to not access the ORM public repository, fork it, etc.. Could cause stability issues whenever a new release is delivered.

Comment: Wouldn't `x => !x.BoolProperty` be misinterpreted here? I would add a check for the UnaryExpression NodeType!

Comment: @MBoros why would you use such an expression for sorting?

Comment: @MatiasCicero Why not? If you want a reverse order on your bool property? If an API allows sorting by expression trees, then it should either do what it is asked to, or throw meaningful errors. Expression trees can represent a really big range of constructs. You should throw meaningful exceptions for not expected input, instead of handling it in an incorrect way. IMHO.

Comment: @MBoros My API would offer two methods `SortAscending` and `SortDescending` so you should never use that kind of expression. At least, that's what LINQ does, for instance.

Comment: @MatiasCicero EF for example allows sorting by much more complex expressions, where the above is totally legal. But of course you design your API as you want, and you handle wrong input again, as your prefer.

Comment: I upvote this and promote it as a possible solution to the driver's provider in its JIRA.